# Get current authenticated user from security context as key for Spring Cache

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-security, ehcache

I have method without parameters and I want to cache return value.
As cache key I want to use current authenticated user from security context

```
@Cacheable(value = "resultCache", key="#userPrincipal.id")
    public result getResult() {}
```

Is it possible or my idea is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have four options to achieve this:

1. Send the `Authentication` object as a method parameter:

   ```java
   @Cacheable(value = "resultCache", key="#authentication.name")
   public Result getResult(Authentication authentication) {}
   ```
2. Create a custom `KeyGenerator` and use it in your `@Cacheable` annotation

   ```java
   public class CustomKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
       @Override
       public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
           return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
       }
   }

   @Configuration
   @EnableCaching
   public class CacheConfiguration {

       @Bean("customKeyGenerator")
       public KeyGenerator customKeyGenerator() {
           return new CustomKeyGenerator();
       }
   }

   @Cacheable(value = "resultCache", keyGenerator="customKeyGenerator")
   public Result getResult() {}
   ```
3. Create a bean that provides you the key and references it via [SPeL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) in the `key` property. I would recommend you going for this approach since it allows you to change the value later more easily.

   ```java
   @Component
   public class CacheKeyProvider {

       public String getUsernameKey() {
           return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
       }
   }

   @Cacheable(value = "resultCache", key="@cacheKeyProvider.getUsernameKey()")
   public Result getResult() {}
   ```
4. Use the [Type SpEL expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types)

   ```java
   @Cacheable(value = "resultCache", key="T(org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder.getContext()?.authentication?.name)")
   public Result getResult() {}
   ```

Note that I used the `name` property from the `Principal` in the examples. But if you have a custom `Principal` object you can cast it and return any property you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. Last solution was what i was looking for, because i don't want to change my method signature.